# How to continue my application after quitting call which is initiated from my app in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

How to continue my application from the same state, after quitting the call which is been done from the app. since we are using iPhone 3.1, I understand that it supports making a call from my application. I'm able to launch the call, but my application is getting terminated before it, so that I'm not able to resume it after quitting the call? how to make sure that my application is not terminated before launching the call?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save your application state applicationWillTerminate, but you only get a limited amount of time to do this. If you are launching the call yourself you could save the data before you begin the call so you won't have any time restrictions.

Alternatively you could upgrade your SDK to 4.0 and use the built-in multitasking functionality. You will still be able to compile apps that run on 3.1, but multi tasking won't be enabled here.